# Function name convention for "convert foo to bar"

Tags: javascript, python, ruby, clojure, lisp

I have a very common pattern of "given a `Foo`, return a `Bar`," for example, given a `user_id`, return a `User`.

Is there a conventional naming pattern for these sorts of functions?  Following [Joel on Software](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html), I've personally used a lot of `bar_from_foo()`, but I rarely see other people do this and it quickly becomes verbose, e.g.

```
widgets = user_widgets_from_user(user_from_param_map(params))
```

Is there a conventional way to name, or namespace (e.g. `User.from_map()`) in any of the popular languages out there?  I am particularly interested in Python but any language you can think of would br useful.

Comment: I like User.from_user_id(user_id)

Comment: and should it be `foo_to_bar()` or `bar_from_foo()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it depends a lot on context and choosing a meaningful metaphor. ActiveRecord for instance uses the class method "find" for finding records in the database, a more meaningful idea than "input a user_id, output a user". For example:

```
User.find(user_id)
User.find_by_email(user_email)
```

For conversions, I usually like to write the conversion methods to make it easy to use in higher order functions. For example in ruby, conversions are often done with `to_*` instance methods, for example to convert a `Foo` to a `Bar` it would make sense to have a `to_bar` method for all foos, so you could write:

```
foo = Foo.new(...)   # make a new Foo
bar = foo.to_bar     # convert it to a Bar
```

And then to convert a bunch of foos, you could simply:

```
bars = foos.map(&:to_bar)
```

Ruby also tends to have `Foo.parse(str)` for converting a string to the object.

---

For javascript, I like having class methods (which I got from standard ml), for example:

```
Foo.toBar = function(foo) {
   return new Bar(...);
};
```

And then you can map over it as well (using underscore in this example):

```
var bars = _.map(foos, Foo.toBar);
```

---

the Standard ML convention is structure (class) methods. Example fn types:

```
Foo.toBar : foo -> bar
Foo.fromBar : bar -> foo
```

And you'd use it like:

```
val bar = Foo.toBar foo;
val bars = map Foo.toBar foos;
```

Answer (score 15):

I would take advantage of Clojure's naming flexibility and call it:

```
(defn foo->bar [] ...)
```

To me that makes the intent quite clear and it's pretty short.

Comment: In Clojure I would leverage open dispatch (multimethods or protocols) and name it just `bar`. I would also try to make it idempotent so that calling it twice is hamrless. That's how `seq` works for example.

Comment: `bar<-foo` might be better. Auto-complete works better if you want a `bar` and it is nicer in nested expressions : `(zed<-baz (baz<-bar (bar<-foo some-foo)))`

Comment: @mikera - You can make the argument either way (I know that when I'm looking for a conversion, I'm thinking "well, I've got a `foo`, but I need to get a `bar`" not "I wish I had a `bar`, but I've got a `foo` instead". YMMV, of course). The `foo->bar` form has been part of RnRS for a while now. *Really*, what you'd want is something like hoogle so that you could search by input/return type rather than name.

Answer (score 6):

In Python, and various other OO languages, this should be a constructor on Bar that takes a single Foo as its only argument. Since Python doesn't do method overloading (and attempts to emulate it are usually fragile), if `Bar.__init__` already takes a different signature, then the convention is exactly your last one. Importantly, this is usually defined as a *class* method rather than a static method (for the benefit of subclasses):

```
 class Bar:
      @classmethod
      def from_foo(cls, f):
          '''Create a new Bar from the given Foo'''
          ret = cls()
          # ...
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to convert something into another, for example a string to an integer, the method is to be defined on the receiver, and hence its class is clear, so you should not put the receiver class as part of the method name: `String#to_i`, not `String#string_to_i`. This in one of the core ideas of object oriented programming (polymorphism).

If the receiver is too general to be assigned such method, for example if `user_id` is a mere string, and defining a method on `String` to convert it to a `User` does not look right, then you should define a constructor method on the class that you expect the return value to be: `User.new` or `User.from_id`.

Answer (score 2):

Why placing the type of the parameter the name of the function? I think it would be clearer something like

```
a_bar = bar_from(a_foo)
```

then you can rely on dynamic dispatch or overload in many languages... for example in Python the implementation could try to call `x.toBar()` if present or it could check for a global registry like `Bar_builders[type(x)](x)`; in Lisp you could rely on methods; in C++ on overloads...